# Human readable file types

Tags: php, file-type, human-readable

Files uploaded to an application have unusually long/complex file types.  For example,

```
icantype.docx: 
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document

lookieloo.pptx
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation
```

While I could grab the extension (which would normally be correct), I'm wondering if there is a cleaner way of getting a simple, short file type.   I don't mind windows-centric file types, since my users are not ever uploading Libre docs.   Using the same examples:

```
icantype.docx: 
Word

lookieloo.pptx
Power Point
```

Does something like this already exist in a built-in function?  Or are there PECL or other classes that provide similar functionality?

Comment: You could probably just get a MIME type list and do the translation yourself. For example: http://www.freeformatter.com/mime-types-list.html

Comment: Wish that list was available in a machine readable version.  Would save time.  Sent the maintainer a note.

Comment: I'm sure it is somewhere. There is likely a mime type file already on your computer.

Comment: Maybe not with the author's added "Name" column & data.  "I took the liberty of adding a name/description for each MIME type so that it's clearer what they represent." - freeformatter

Comment: Here's a pipe-delimited file (CSV) with the data (minus links on the far right): https://www.dropbox.com/s/9a88b5iy9mue34l/mime_types_from_freeformatter.csv.   Or if you prefer ODS, https://www.dropbox.com/s/i6x9itln84r272o/mime_types_from_freeformatter.ods

Comment: Here's a MySQL dump file with the same data (details link and text in separate colums): https://www.dropbox.com/s/l621lrhcpyu4beo/lookup_mime_type.sql

Comment: You should post those as an answer so you can accept it and close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not finding a built in function to supply this information, but [freeformatter.com](http://freeformatter.com) put together a comprehensive and expanded list of [MIME types and descriptions](http://www.freeformatter.com/mime-types-list.html).

I've extracted data from this page and put into machine-readable files.  All credit to [freeformatter.com](http://freeformatter.com).

Pipe-delimited file (CSV), minus links under Details.
http://dropbox.com/s/9a88b5iy9mue34l/mime_types_from_freeformatter.csv.

ODS spreadsheet with the same data.
http://dropbox.com/s/i6x9itln84r272o/mime_types_from_freeformatter.ods

Here's a MySQL dump file with the same data (details link and text in separate colums): http://dropbox.com/s/l621lrhcpyu4beo/lookup_mime_type.sql